# Continue option not available

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I exited out of a run and when I tried to go back, they continue button was greyed out and unusable. Is this a glitch? May I have done something wrong?

Comment: I searched on SteamCommunity, and it seems a known bug (as december 2014), but I don't know if it was fixed. What kind of run was? Were you dying when you exited?

Comment: I was not dying. I had full health, however i was blowing up the entire room prior to exiting and there were little explosion and frames that stayed after the explosions themselves subsided.

Comment: It was probably just some sort of bug. You can't reproduce it, I reckon?